# Having an issue where Opportunity Line item quantity resets when we update a custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to add a dynamic 'remove pass' row from my pageblocktable

so far i have :

```
 <apex:commandLink value="Add Row" action="{!addRow}" rerender="table,error"/>
```

which goes to:

```
 public void addrow(){
    lstpassregs.add(new CXT_Pass_Registration__c());
    system.debug(lstpassregs);
}
```

DEBUG: DEBUG|(CXT_Pass_Registration__c:{Id=a1D8E000000ojfqUAA}, 
CXT_Pass_Registration__c:{}, CXT_Pass_Registration__c:{}, CXT_Pass_Registration__c:{}, CXT_Pass_Registration__c:{}, CXT_Pass_Registration__c:{})

However i need to be able to remove that row in case they add one in mistake etc.. I tried this :

```
public void deleteRow(){
    CXT_Pass_Registration__c passreg = new CXT_Pass_Registration__c();
    //lstpassregs.remove();
    lstpassregs.remove(passreg);
}
```

However i get the error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List].remove(CXT_Pass_Registration__c)

Anyone know how i could solve this?

EDIT:

I used

```
> for(deleteNumber = 0; deleteNumber < lstpassregs.size();
> deleteNumber++){ lstpassregs.remove(deleteNumber); }
```

However I think I need a way for the addnumber to have the same sort of thing as it deletes more than 1 row?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant remove an item from the list directly using remove method in salesforce.You have to use an index for it to remove.For eg:
if the index of the row to be deleted is 0

```
lstpassregs.remove(0);
```

will remove the value at the 0

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That has helped! thank you ill just do a for loop so i know which row is which thanks!

Comment: I used
for(deleteNumber = 0; deleteNumber < lstpassregs.size(); deleteNumber++){
               lstpassregs.remove(deleteNumber);
        }

However I think I need a way for the addnumber to have the same sort of thing as it deletes more than 1 row?

Comment: What's the condition to delete the record?

Comment: Its just a commandlink that i want to delete that row from the pageblocktable lstpassregs.add(new CXT_Pass_Registration__c()); thats the add commandlink and the remove commandlink i just need to remove anyone that can get added

Comment: Will this command link be at each row of the related record?

Comment: Yes, ill take a screenshot to the above question to show what i mean

Comment: Just added screenshot to show what it currently looks like

Comment: Okay please add the following to make it work.You need the exact row to be deleted.This can  be done by using apex:variable and looping through the loop to increase the variable count.Pass that variable in your deleterow method to delete the variable of that particular index.Please see the below blog for further things:   http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/12/adding-and-deleting-rows-dynamically-in.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46424/discussion-between-clevelanddan-and-preya-mohandoss).